# Is there a formal name for an "undecorated" variable?

Tags: notation

That is, is there a term to specifically distinguish the type of thing `x` is, as juxtaposed with `x'`, `x''`, etc?

The [wikipedia page on the prime symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_(symbol)) mentions that "The prime is said to "decorate" the letter to which it applies.", which gives me that idea that perhaps "undecorated variable" is the term I'm looking for, but I haven't found any examples of people using it. Is there a standard term for this?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: I have never come across either term.  Subscripts and superscripts usually have well defined meanings without calling anything decorated.  I feel this subject is a blind ally.

Comment: I have come across both terms, and a quick internet search produced [this example](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05557) of a paper using your phrase "undecorated variables".

Comment: @herbsteinberg But decorations like tildes and primes aren't really subscripts or superscripts in the traditional sense, hence it's useful to have a term for them.

Comment: @Mark S What makes the term useful?  In all my years in mathematics I had never heard of them.

Comment: @herb steinberg If you need a lot of related compact notation with primes and such, you might want to explain to the reader the significance of the undecorated variables. That's done at least in the paper I linked, in the CS book "The Z notation: A Reference Manual", and a couple papers on automata. But I think I first came across this meaning of "undecorated" in undergraduate lectures, probably in place of the cumbersome "without a prime/tilde". For instance, if a transformation turned $x,y$ into $x',y'$ respectively, but a conclusion about the latter helped say something about the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No, no such name exists … besides "undecorated".

<sup>I'm posting this CW answer so that users who **confidently** concur that the answer to the question is "*No*" have an answer to vote on, and so this question doesn't stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). If however anyone has an affirmative response to the question, please downvote this and post your answer.</sup>

Comment: accepting this primarily because I am convinced by Mark S.'s link to this paper that actually uses the term: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05557.pdf